# How to properly use Math.log?

Tags: java.util.scanner, logarithm

So I got this formula to calculate the number of years it takes to double any amount of money with a given interest (i)

```
log(2) / log(1 + (i/100) )
```

So here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication37 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("What's the interest rate?: ");
        int i = reader.nextInt(); 
        double t = (Math.log(2))/(Math.log(1+(i/100)));
        System.out.println("It takes " + t + " years before the amount has doubled");
    }
}
```

That gives me the output: It takes Infinity years before the amount has doubled

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about Java. But if `i` is an `int`, wouldn't `i/100` be `0`? Consequently `log(1+(i/100))` becomes `log(1+0)` = `log(1)` = `0`, and therefore `log(2)/0` which is infinity. Basically, try converting `i` to a `double` instead?

Comment: Thanks! I must have been sleeping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `100` is assumed as integer. You should rather write 100 is as `100.0` and it will run.
This is because values as `1.0`, `2.3` assumed as double and not float. Notice the decimal point.

so rewrite you code as below and it will run:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication37 {




    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("What's the interest rate?: ");
    int i = reader.nextInt(); 
    double t = (Math.log(2))/(Math.log(1+(i/100.0)));
    System.out.println("It takes " + t + " years before the amount has doubled");

    }

}
```

[image]